# global name 'sqrt' not defined

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

I've created a function, `potential(x,K,B,N)`, where `x`,`K`,`B` are `numpy` arrays and `N` is an integer. I'm trying to test the function in `iPython` but I keep getting the error `"global name 'sqrt' not defined"`.

Here's a look at my code:

```
def potential(x,K,B,N):

    x = x.reshape((3,N),order='F')

U_b = 0.0
for i in xrange(0,N-1):
    for j in xrange(i+1,N):
        if K[i,j] == 1.0:
            U_b += sum((x[:,i]-x[:,j])**2)
U_b = 0.5*U_b

U_a = 0.0
for i in xrange(0,N-2):
    for j in xrange(i+1,N-1):
        for l in xrange(j+1,N):
            if B[i,j,l] == 1.0:
                U_a += B[i,j,l]*sum((x[:,i]-x[:,j])*(x[:,j]-x[:,l]))/(sqrt(sum((x[:,i]-x[:,j])**2))*sqrt(sum((x[:,j]-x[:,l])**2)))
U_a = -U_a

U_r = 0.0
d = 0.0
for i in xrange(0,N-1):
    for j in xrange(i+1,N):
        d = sqrt(sum((x[:,i]-x[:,j])**2))
        if d > sqrt(0.2):
            U_r += (1.0/6.0)*(1/(d**6))
        else:
            U_r += -0.2**(-7.0/2.0)*d + (7.0/6.0)*(0.2)**(-3)

return U_b + U_a + U_r
```

I've tried using `from math import *` but that doesn't seem to help. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 20):

Add the missing line:

```
from numpy import sqrt
```

(or in non-NumPy code `from math import sqrt`. Note that  these are two different functions:[`numpy.sqrt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sqrt.html) also accepts vectors and arrays , but plain `math.sqrt` doesn't)

> I've tried using `from math import *` but that doesn't seem to help.

(Possibly you did that after defining the function. Anyway, fuhgeddaboutit, just reload the code in a clean session, it will work.)

UPDATES:

- strictly, in Python you're supposed to do `import package` not `from package import identifier1 [,identifier2, identifier3...]` and *never* `from package import *`. But `from package import identifier1` is ok when judiciously used, if you don't overdo it, and locally inside a function. If it's unambiguous, and you're going to be doing a lot of it, it shortens the code e.g. `sqrt()` instead of `math.sqrt()`, `log` instead of `math.log10()`
- `sqrt` is not a builtin in Python, unlike R. So yes in Python you need either `from numpy import sqrt` or `import math` or `from math import sqrt` before you can use it.

Comment: Do we always need to {import} before using the function? In R,even if you do not use other package, you still have some built-function to use by just typing {sqrt} with {import} first?

Comment: @Phdaml: sqrt is not a builtin in Python, unlike R. So yes in Python you need either `import math` or `from math import sqrt`

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged numpy,

```
import numpy as np
```

Then use `np.sqrt` instead of `sqrt`. Always works.

Comment: I did that before I posted this. My apologies for not stating that in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here:

**Additional libraries: e.g., `NumPy`**

```
import numpy as np
```

and then use `np.sqrt(9)`

or

```
from numpy import sqrt
sqrt(9)
```

**Or Standard Library and in-built solutions:**

**1)** `9**0.5`

**2)**

```
import math
math.sqrt(9)
```

or

```
from math import sqrt
sqrt(9)
```

For the latter part, I'd prefer the `math` function for performance reasons. I did this benchmark here:

[image]

Why is the math module more efficient?
The math module uses the C implementations of the square root

The code for my benchmark can be found here:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/One-Python-benchmark-per-day/blob/master/ipython_nbs/day8_sqrt_and_exp.ipynb?create=1

Answer (score 0):

just add.

```
from math import sqrt
```

Comment: I also did this before posting

Answer (score 0):

There are two options, first is
from math import * and use the square root function as *sqrt()*
otherwise
*import math* and use the square root function as *math.sqrt()*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).